# Replace coordinates in KML file with python3

Tags: python, xml, kml, pykml

I need to replace all coordinates in a KML file:

```
<coordinates>
24.6206,58.0265,10
24.6218,58.0245,260
24.6234,58.0221,510
24.6257,58.0191,760
</coordinates>
```

I tried in this way but root is empty at the end:

```
from pykml import parser
import requests

kmlFile = requests.get('https://predict.habhub.org/kml.php',params=ploadsKml)
root = parser.fromstring(bytes(kmlFile.text, encoding='utf8'))
    
coordinates_before = root.Document.Placemark.LineString.coordinates
string_updated_coordinates="'\\n34.4534,56.5675\\n34.4786,57.1274\\n'"
updated_coordinates = literal_eval(string_updated_coordinates)
coordinates_before._setText(updated_coordinates)
print (root)
```

but root is empty.

Here the full kml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
<name>Flight Path</name>
<description><![CDATA[Flight data be3aa40 <br>Site: 58.02651, 24.62057 at 14:5 on 26/12/2020]]></description>
<Placemark>
<name>Path</name>
<description>Test v.78</description>
<styleUrl>#yellowPoly</styleUrl>
<LineString>
<extrude>1</extrude>
<tesselate>1</tesselate>
<altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
<coordinates>
24.6206,58.0265,10
24.6218,58.0245,260
24.6234,58.0221,510
24.6257,58.0191,760
</coordinates>
</LineString></Placemark>
<Placemark>
<name>Balloon Launch</name>
<description>GPS TEST 58.0265, 24.6206 </description>
<Point><coordinates>32.6206,78.0265,0</coordinates></Point>
</Placemark>
</Document></kml>
```

Only those 4 coordinates need to be replaced keeping the remaining info in kml file.

Comment: Kml file is downloaded from https://predict.habhub.org. I use original coordinates to make some calculations and generate new ones. After that new coordinates have to replace the original ones.

Comment: Your KML is not valid the `<Document>`  `<description>` tag contains invalid characters (`<` and `>`).

Comment: I corrected description tag

Comment: Yes I import parser and requests

Comment: If want to print the root, need to serialize it, `print(etree.tostring(etree.ElementTree(root), pretty_print=True))`

Answer (score 1):

Namespace in kml gave me problems too. So I managed in this way, it works, sure there are other ways:

```
root = lxml.html.fromstring(bytes(kmlFile, encoding='utf8'))

ns = {"kml": "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"}

tree  = etree.parse("myfile1.kml")
for simple_data in tree.xpath("/kml:kml/kml:Document/kml:Placemark/kml:LineString/kml:coordinates", namespaces=ns):  
    simple_data.text=gpsString
    
with open(OUTPUTFILE, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(etree.tostring(tree))
```